# How to link words with cleveref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

Is it possible to link a word to the meaning at the end of file with `cleveref`?

Heres a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    Today I ran like a \label{cheetah}cheetah and it was amazing to feel the wind.

    \pagebreak

    \cref{cheetah}: is a large cat of the subfamily Felinae that occurs in North, Southern and East Africa, and a few localities in Iran. It inhabits a variety of mostly arid habitats like dry forests, scrub forests, and savannahs.
\end{document}
```

I wish the name cheetah in the sentence could be a link to the meaning at the end of the document and when I called `\cref{cheetah}` it showed only the name cheetah and not a number.

Comment: I think this is exactly what packages like `gloassaries-extra` are meant to do. It's their nature and would not require any extra manual work. You can define entries, then use them within in the text body. Together with `hyperref`, they will turn into links. These take you to a glossary, where many features are available, like a long explanation and a list of page numbers where the term was used.

Comment: I'll take a look on that package. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's good news and bad news. The bad news is that you cannot use `\label` and `\cref` to achieve your cross-referencing goal. This is because, given your setup LaTeX cannot meaningfully associate `\label` with a recently-incremented counter variable.

But there's also good news! You can fully achieve your typesetting goal by using the `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` macros of the `hyperref` package. Both `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` are macros which take two arguments. The first must be the same -- `cheetah_def` in the example below. The second is free-format -- `cheetah` and `\textbf{Cheetah}`, respectively, in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Today I ran like a \hyperlink{cheetah_def}{cheetah} and 
it was amazing to feel the wind.

\pagebreak

\noindent
\hypertarget{cheetah_def}{\textbf{Cheetah}}: A large cat 
of the subfamily Felinae that occurs in North, Southern 
and East Africa, and a few localities in Iran. It inhabits 
a variety of mostly arid habitats such as dry forests, 
scrub forests, and savannahs.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was what I needed.